# jshint error: Redefinition of '$'

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js, jshint

I have a Node.js web application where I use Backbone.js and jQuery. My main js file is `app.js` where I include all the necessary scripts, including jQuery. So, this is the beginning of my app.js code:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var $ = require('jquery');
var B = require('backbone');
B.$ = $;
```

Now if I run `grunt` on my project, it raises errors at the line where jQuery is loaded to $. It shows me this:

```
Linting public/js/app.js ...ERROR
[L4:C5] W079: Redefinition of '$'.
var $ = require('jquery');
```

I can still get everything running with `grunt --force`, but I would like to eliminate this error anyway. Can somebody explain why it raises the error and how to fix it?

---

My `.jshintrc` file:

```
{
    "laxcomma": true
    ,"laxbreak": true
    ,"curly": true
    ,"eqeqeq": true
    ,"immed": true
    ,"latedef": true
    ,"newcap": true
    ,"noarg": true
    ,"sub": true
    ,"undef": true
    ,"unused": false
    ,"asi": true
    ,"boss": true
    ,"eqnull": true
    ,"node": true
    ,"browser": true
    ,"jquery": true
    ,"predef":
    [
        "suite"
        ,"test"
        ,"setup"
        ,"teardown"
        ,"suiteSetup"
        ,"suiteTeardown"
        ,"requestAnimationFrame"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess you use grunt-contrib-jshint (Grunt by itself doesn't do code validation) -- edit if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Terry - can you post your JSHint config? You shouldn't receive this warning by default.

Comment: Yes, this is a definitely a jshint configuration issue.

Comment: I updated the question with my .jshintrc file content. Anything unusual there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In jshint docs: http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/

```
jquery = true 
This option defines globals exposed by the jQuery JavaScript library.
```

You are telling jshint that jquery exists, thus he assumes that $ is defined. Remove the `"jquery" : true"` and your issue should go away.

Comment: You mean, instead of doing `var $ = require('jquery');`, I should do `require('jquery');`?

Comment: @Terry yeah either that or configure jQuery Modules to exclude attaching global jQuery variables

Comment: Ok I think I don't quite get it yet what you are saying. What do you mean by attaching global jQuery variables? Like `B.$ = $;`?

Comment: @Terry what they say in https://www.npmjs.org/package/jquery/ is that when you require jQuery it defines the global variable $ and jQuery.

Comment: Ok I got it now I think. It makes sense to not use `var $` because it will redefine the very global variable `$` of jQuery. If I do that, grunt doesn't show the error anymore. However, the javascript in app.js then doesn't find $ in the next line (`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`). Why is that? Shouldn't it be there? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Terry deleted old answer and checked jshint docs. You should check if this solves it.

Comment: That works. However, I'm wondering why `$` is not defined as a global variable if jquery is requested, as I would have expected.

Comment: @Terry you would have to actually have $ defined as global variable in your code, which as we've concluded is not the case. jshint doesn't pull in dependencies, you can only tell it which ones you have defined (in this case you are telling `$` is defined as global when it isn't)

Comment: So I guess this is probably an issue with the jquery that I'm requesting, that it just doesn't define `$` as a global variable?
Anyway, thank you, this helped already.

Comment: Jquery doesn't define global variable because it understands it's included as CommonJS module and there is no need for global variable. +1 to this answer, it's a pure jshint problem which doesn't check if global variables actually exist.

Answer (score 6):

Add this at the top of the file to make that error go away:

`/* jshint -W079 */`

What's happening here is that JQuery defines the $ variable, so JSHint views this as a piece of ["potentially dangerous code"](http://jslinterrors.com/redefinition-of-a)

A better solution would be to require jquery directly which should give you access to the $ variable globally.

Comment: Telling the error to go away is the same as goind `grunt --force` which is something the OP doesn't want. The second option is ok but very ugly hack that just hides the issue

Comment: I see what you mean, although "very ugly hack" isn't exactly informative.

Comment: haha fair point, so if you just define a variable to workaround the issue. Then that would propagate into every time you had the issue (probably happening in other files as well) you would have more and more variable declarations, that wouldn't be doing anything and just polluting the code. It would very quickly turn into bad practice/code smell

Answer (score 0):

Random guess: do you include jquery somewhere else? For example in some html file as a script. Or some other script might be defining global jquery variable.

Comment: No, I double-checked, and it is not included before this call.

Comment: what if you add ```console.log(typeof $);``` before the require call?

Comment: Before the require call it is `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your .jshintrc you don't have '$' set as predefined.

```
// Predefined Globals
"predef" : ["$"]
```

If it is, remove.